# Send HTML mail not as text

Tags: html, email, rendering, html-email

I'm getting mad with this.
My goal is to send a mail that contains HTML.
I have read tons of tutorials and i want to send a HTML like:

```
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
           hola
      </body> 
</html>
```

but if i paste it in mail the result is the code as text, can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you mean do you want to send html code throuh the mail?

Comment: @Simo, when you say "send an email (...)" you mean YOU, manually, by copying/pasting the HTML code into a composer like gmail, or you mean by code? if code, which programming language? If manually, try opening the html with a browser, copying it and then pasting it manually into let's say, gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are unfamiliar with PHP or another coding language and just want a quick way to slap some html into an email.

Quickest way is to open your html in a browser, then `ctrl+a` highlighting everything in the browser window, then copy and paste it into the body of your email. The rendered html will then remain rendered. Just make sure any images you link to are absolute (hosted online, starting with `http://`, and not on your computer), otherwise your email recipient will not see them.

Keep in mind, this is a quick hack technique. If you are going to send emails to groups of people frequently, you should use an email service provider like Campaign Monitor, Mailchimp or Constant Contact.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $from = $systemAdmin;
        $emailTo=$email;
           $subject="New";
       $body="<html>
         <head>
         </head>
             <body>
               hola
              </body> 
          </html>";
         //to call function for mail()
         if(sendMail($emailTo,$subject,$body,$from))
         {
       return 'fail';
         }
         else
           {
      return 'success';
          }
        function sendMail($sentTo,$subject,$message,$from) // send email function
          {
          $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
          $headers .= "From: $from\r\n";
          $headers .= "Bcc: rahul@gmail.com\r\n";
          $headers .= "Bcc: ravi@gmail.com\r\n";

       if(is_array($sentTo))
        {
          foreach($sentTo as $email){ //to add multiple mail in 'To'
        mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
     }
        }
        else
        {
      mail($sentTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
         }
```

Comment: this is the updated code in php language ,please check if these things are included in your code or not